# Laravel, VueJS app blank page on production

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, vue.js, web-deployment

I have Laravel 5.6 app with VueJS deployed on my AWS instance. PHP version on the production is 7.2 (to run Laravel5.6)
But I am seeing just a blank page, views are not loading. I have executed the commands
`npm install`
`npm run dev`

The application is working fine on my local. All the environment settings are same.
The only difference is, I am accessing my AWS application using public IP i.e. http://myip.0.0.1/app-name/public
I have nothing in logs. 
Any thing I have missed here? Or how can I debug this?

**UPDATE**
here are the errors that I am seeing in console
[image]

Comment: I assume you've also ran composer install?

Comment: What do you see in Chrome Dev Tools console? Any errors?

Comment: @Adam, yes I ran `composer update`, not `composer install`

Comment: @matiit, see my updates in the question

Comment: You need remove vendor folder in project, after you run composer install again

Comment: Tried that too. didn't work